# Javascript Execution not entering for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am facing a really odd problem when executing my JS code. My code execution is not entering a `for` loop and there are no errors in the console. When I try executing the loop by typing directly in the console, it is executing. Here is the loop :

```
for(var x = 0; x <= distance; x++) {
            var yMinusY1Sq = distance*distance - (x - startX)*(x - startX)
            var yMinusy1Cal = parseInt(Math.sqrt(yMinusY1Sq));
            console.log(yMinusY1Sq, yMinusy1Cal);
            if((yMinusY1Sq == yMinusy1Cal*yMinusy1Cal)) {
                y = yMinusY1Cal + startY;
                var point = document.createElement("div");
                point.className = "output-point";
                point.style.height =  (grid.offsetHeight/16).toString() + "px";
                point.style.width =  (grid.offsetWidth/16).toString() + "px";
                outputPoints.appendChild(point);
                point.style.top = y*oneBoxY;
                point.style.left = (x+startX)*oneBoxX;
                isodistancePoints.push(point);
            }
        }
```

Here, `distance` is `>=` 1. The `console.log` inside the loop is not executing and printing anything. While, if another `console.log` is put just before the loop, it is printing. So, what is going wrong?

**Edit**
I tried printing `distance`, which is a global variable, just before the loop, it is showing `undefined`, but if it is printed directly using the console, it gives a `number` value. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Here, is the order of initialization and function, the other global variables initialized are working fine.

```
var distance;

init();

function init() {
    distance = 1;
    //Other code
}

$("#run").bind('click', function () {
    // some other code
    for(var x = 0; x <= distance; x++) {
        // some code
    }
});
```

Comment: use F12 to see error in console

Comment: @HienNguyen Kind of questioning why you're commenting that? Op clearly says `there are no errors in the console` and it's not logging. I don't think the issue is not knowing how to open the console here :P

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @CalebGoodman chrome

Comment: You should check the value of `distance`.  If it is somehow 0 or 1 then your loop wont execute.

Comment: _if another console.log is put just before the loop, it is printing_, what are you printing? are you printing the `distance`? Is it definitely `>=1` and also a number (make sure it's not a string)

Comment: I just printed `distance`, it is showing undefined. But `distance` is a global variable and has already been defined. If `distance` is directly put into the console, it gives the output as a number, but when printed  before loop, it is showing undefined

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the part where you declare the `distance` variable so we can see if this is within the scope of where it should be

Comment: I edited the question, `distance` is global, otherwise, I won't be able to print it otherwise.

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/geL2sbch/ That might help you understand how your `distance` might be undefined before the loop but work fine in console.

Comment: @icecub I still don't get why that is happening. why is the global variable not retaining value outside the function it is defined? also, my other global functions, which are storing frequently used `DOM` objects work fine, even though they are defined in the same function as `distance`.

Comment: That is why we asked you to edit your question and show us how `distance` is declared and how it's value is being set. We can't tell you what's going on if we can't see the actual problem. If the value is not set before the loop executes, it's undefined. If the value is set wrongly, it's set to a local scope and not a global one, even though they have the same name. We don't know unless we can see it.

Comment: @icecub I edited. the other `DOM` variables work fine. even when used before the same loop

Comment: You're still not showing us everything we need. We need to see where `distance` is declared and its relation between your `init()` function and your loop call. Also, please don't unclude all the other code. It's not needed to solve the issue :)

Comment: @ShantanuShinde I'm guessing your calling `init()` when the page loads? If this is the case, your `for` loop code will run before `init()` is called (if it doesn't sit within your `init()` function), and so `distance` won't be set (similar to what's happening in icecub's snippet). You're probably better of initializing your `distance` variable outside the `init()` method

Comment: @NickParsons the loop runs on clicking a button. So, no, it does not run before `init`

Comment: Before this becomes an endless list of comments, please edit your question and show us in this exact order: `distance` declaration. `init()` function call. Loop initialization. When we have that info, we can get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @ShantanuShinde please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or your problem so people can better assist you. At the moment, you're lacking context and so we're just playing a guessing game

Comment: I'm fairly certain that's not how your code is setup. As you can see, that code works perfectly fine: https://jsfiddle.net/bd5fcqL9/

Comment: @icecub I got the problem. there was if statement before the loop and the loop is in the else. in the if I had a local variable named `distance`

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: @ShantanuShinde put that last comment as an answer if yours problem got solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the loop was inside an `else` statement, and the `if` of the statement had a local variable named `distance`. I still don't know the exact cause of the error, as the execution is not supposed to go into the `if` because its condition is not satisfied, but renaming the variable worked and now I am getting desired output. But if anyone knows the exact reason, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is in the console. What gets logged is a reference not the value of the object in time. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

> Please be warned that if you log objects in
>   the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox what you get logged on the
>   console is a reference to the object, which is not necessarily the
>   'value' of the object at the moment in time you call console.log(),
>   but it is the value of the object at the moment you open the console.

And the solution is

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(distance))
```

or

```
console.log(`${distance}`)
```

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem. I have defined the global variable in a function that is called before the loop, but still during the loop, the value is showing undefined

Comment: as people write you in the comments you have a problem in another place in the code. at least now you can debug it and be sure what is printed is what the value of the variable at that time. look for local variables with same name (overshadowing the global one) or running order is not what you expect.

Comment: Although the information in your answer is indeed usefull, I have to agree with @ShantanuShinde here that it does not answer the question.

Comment: in light of missing information in the question this is  the best solution i can provide ( a tool  to find the root cause)